# How to return all items from local storage?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have five items saved into my localStorage and each includes their own key and value. My end goal is to return an HTML list with each item included on it. The current code does not return anything, if you have any idea or any other way let me know.

Thanks!

```js
showLocalStorage = () => {
      this.arrayLocalStorage = [];
      for(var i=0, len=localStorage.length; i<len; i++) {
        let key = localStorage.key(i)
        let value = localStorage[key]
        this.arrayLocalStorage.push(value)
      }
      this.arrayLocalStorage.map(item => {return item})
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get all your localStorage keys by using . Object.keys()

```
const allKeys = Object.keys(localstorage);
```

then you can return the list like this

```
return <ul> 
        { allKeys.map(key => <li> {localstorage.getItem(key)} </li>) }
    </ul>
```

Comment: `allKeys` is not defined.

Comment: I know I can access it this way aswell, but how do I return the whole list?

Comment: the second line of my answer lists all the values inside an array. From there you can do whatever you like with the values

Comment: It lists but the issue is, I've tried mapping, foreach it etc but can't seem to find a way to make it return in HTML as a whole list.

Comment: It should be `localStorage` (capital 'S'), not `localstorage`.

Answer (score 0):

Get local storage data in an object:

```
var rtn={};
Object.keys(localStorage).map(function(key){
  rtn[key] = localStorage.getItem(key);
});
return rtn;
```